# Setting Focusable After Button Event

Tags: java, swing, focus, jbutton, keyboard-events

Ok so I have a JButton to restart my game.

```
private static class Clicked implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        hero.setHealth(100);
        cl.show(cards, sGame);
    }
}
```

After I press the button the keyboard listener doens't work.  I looked it up and it seems like the window is losing focus.  I already have setfocusable and adding the keylistener in my game panel:

```
addKeyListener(new Keys());
setFocusable(true);
setDoubleBuffered(true);
```

Do I do something after the button event or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window's not losing focus, the button is gaining focus, taking it away from your component with the `KeyListener`.

In your investigations, you should have also found out that `KeyListener` will only respond to key events when the component is focusable AND has focus.  This is a known limitation of `KeyListener`...

Also in your investigations, you should have found that [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) is normally recommended as fix to this problem...